# PHP Login (Form submit links to loginprocess.php but nothing happens(blank page))

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

I'm trying to create a login page using Mysql, I checked DB connection and such everything works as intended. However I've created the loginprocess now but when submitting the login information it just links me to the loginprocess.php and nothing else happens. I tried searching for a while but everyone's issue what that they didn't give the username input a name.

Here's my code for the **index.php** (login screen)

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
<header>

</header>

<section>

    <div class="nav-login">
    <form action="includes/loginprocess.php" method="POST">
        <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input class="txtbox" type="password" name="userpass" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <button class="good-looking" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button> 
    </form>

    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the **loginprocess.php** (it's in includes folder)

```
 <?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include 'dbconn.php';

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $userpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userpass']);

    if (empty($username) || empty($userpass)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM samokslogin WHERE samokslogin_username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $reultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($resultCheck < 1) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
        exit();
        } else {
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $LoginCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['samokslogin_userpass']);
                if($LoginCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=failed");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($LoginCheck == true) {
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['samokslogin_id']; 
                $_SESSION['u_username'] = $row['samokslogin_username']; 
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=failed");
        exit();
    }
```

I really did search for a long time, and re-read all my codes to make sure I've even tried using try catch to see the error but nothing came up. I hope I'm not missing something obvious..

Best regards :)
-Samo

Comment: A blank page is a 500 internal server error displayed on a server not set up for development. You should turn on all error reporting when developing, so you're not stumbling blind when the error is right there in front of you

Comment: try commenting exit and then check if result is same or not

Comment: @JimL Hey, thanks for answering so quickly I'm going to check :)

Comment: you code has syntax errors see there is if else else.move last else to match first if

Comment: why you are using else inside if condition. just remove or replace the last else block out of if condition

Comment: @Naveen Ohh I missed that one, thanks for pointing it out. However the problem persists it's probably a server error as JimL mentioned I'm currently using a webhost to test my php files out I'm going to try it on my server now to see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had made a slim mistake by forgetting the $username = mysqli_real_escape**_string**($conn, $_POST['username']) after checking the error logs I've now fixed it, thanks to everyone who helped me out with this one it's my first php project I wasn't sure if there were error logs at all even.